# Destaque em trecho de SMS

Tags: ux, sms

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de enviar um SMS, e deixar destacado uma parte do texto para que o usuário possa copiar. Por exemplo, a linha digitável de um boleto.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde sei, os protocolos de envio de SMS não dão suporte a formatação de texto. O motivo disso é que cada aparelho pode ter tratamentos diferentes para os textos que recebe. Isso nunca foi unificado (ao contrário de coisas como email e MMS), então um texto em negrito ou itálico em um aparelho poderia aparecer com caracteres estranhos ao usuário em outro aparelho.

Se você precisa usar SMS, a melhor forma é fazer como a VIVO faz. Ela manda mensagens do tipo:

> Sua fatura já pode ser paga, utilize o código:
>
> XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX X XXX

Os únicos "destaques" são as quebras de linha. Em qualquer telemóvel com Android ou iOS, é trivial para o usuário selecionar o código de barras e copiar para colar em um aplicativo de mensagem instantânea ou de *Internet Banking*.

Comment: Utilizei o quebra linha, porém ele copia o texto todo da mensagem ainda...

Comment: @LuizFernando então o problema é o aplicativo de leitura, não a mensagem em si.

Answer (score 0):

Eu também não consegui copiar apenas o código do SMS.

A solução que encontrei foi inserir o código entre aspas.

Então todos os apps de banco que testei interpretaram somente o valor que estava entre aspas.

A mensagem que envio ficou assim:

> Empresa A: Copie esse SMS e cole no APP do seu banco para efetuar o
>   pagamento: "99999.75021 48600.000000 56224.501017 1 77310000079009"